# HTML SSI's don't work in browser

Tags: html, dreamweaver, ssi

I'm trying to use server side includes for both my header and navigation, as they will be constant across every page, and I'd like the ability to make frequent changes in one place and have them populate across all pages. I have tried a "file" and "virtual" include, and have tired placing the include files in the same directory. The include files have no duplicate code (doctype indicator, html tag, etc). I've also tried both .html and .shtml file extensions. I use the file explorer in DW to select the files, so I'm assuming the path is correct.

The SSI's preview fine in Dreamweaver, but will not populate in the browser. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!--#include virtual="/lpapp/includes/influencer_header.shtml" -->       
    <!--#include virtual="/lpapp/includes/influencer_sidebar.shtml" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver probably support SSI. If you run your html from a random folder on your local PC, SSI won't work. As soon as you upload the project to a Apache webserver or a virtual server like Wamp/Mamp. It is possible to get SSI working using the right SSI syntax and .htaccess.